# Is this postgresql logging handler correct?

Tags: python, logging, multiprocessing, psycopg2

I'm trying to develop a logging handler for PostgreSQL. I've used [this gist](https://gist.github.com/ykessler/2662203#file-sqlite_handler-py) as a template and changed that to suit my needs as

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import psycopg2
import logging
import time

## Logging handler for PostgreSQL
#
#
class psqlHandler(logging.Handler):

    initial_sql = """CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS log(
                        Created text,
                        Name text,
                        LogLevel int,
                        LogLevelName text,
                        Message text,
                        Args text,
                        Module text,
                        FuncName text,
                        LineNo int,
                        Exception text,
                        Process int,
                        Thread text,
                        ThreadName text
                   )"""

    insertion_sql = """INSERT INTO log(
                            Created,
                            Name,
                            LogLevel,
                            LogLevelName,
                            Message,
                            Module,
                            FuncName,
                            LineNo,
                            Exception,
                            Process,
                            Thread,
                            ThreadName) VALUES (
                            %(created)s,
                            %(name)s,
                            %(levelno)s,
                            %(levelname)s,
                            %(msg)s,
                            %(module)s,
                            %(funcName)s,
                            %(lineno)s,
                            %(exc_text)s,
                            %(process)s,
                            %(thread)s,
                            %(threadName)s
                    );"""

    def connect(self):
        try:
            self.__connect = psycopg2.connect(
                database=self.__database,
                host = self.__host,
                user = self.__user,
                password = self.__password,
                sslmode="disable")

            return True
        except:
            return False

    def __init__(self, params):

        if not params:
            raise Exception ("No database where to log ☻")

        self.__database = params['database']
        self.__host = params['host']
        self.__user = params['user']
        self.__password = params['password']

        self.__connect = None

        if not self.connect():
            raise Exception ("Database connection error, no logging ☻")

        logging.Handler.__init__(self)

        self.__connect.cursor().execute(psqlHandler.initial_sql)
        self.__connect.commit()
        self.__connect.cursor().close()

    def emit(self, record):

        # Use default formatting:
        self.format(record)

        if record.exc_info:
            record.exc_text = logging._defaultFormatter.formatException(record.exc_info)
        else:
            record.exc_text = ""

        # Insert log record:
        try:
            cur = self.__connect.cursor()
        except:
            self.connect()
            cur = self.__connect.cursor()

        cur.execute(psqlHandler.insertion_sql, record.__dict__)

        self.__connect.commit()
        self.__connect.cursor().close()
if __name__ == "__main__":

    myh = psqlHandler({'host':"localhost", 'user':"test",
                       'password':"testpw", 'database':"test"})

    l = logging.getLogger("TEST")
    l.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    l.addHandler(myh)


    for i in xrange(1):
        l.info("test%i"%i)
```

What I would like to know is if this logger is correct (apparently works) and if it would work in a multiprocessing environment.
Thanks.

Comment: Your module is fine, concurrency-wise.   Concurrent inserts are well handled in PostgreSQL.  If there are any issues, it would not be there.